# Writing a RESX file with no resources

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I am using a `ResXResourceWriter` and `ResXResourceReader` to handle resources from a `.resx` file. In order to "remove" a resource I load all the items from the reader and just don't add that one to the writer.

I noticed a problem whenever I tried to remove all resources from a file: the writer throws a `NullReferenceException`. Example simplified code.

```
var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(filename);
writer.Close();
```

Reading through the [source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Windows.Forms/System.Resources/ResXResourceWriter.cs) for `ResXResourceWriter` the internal writer isn't initiated until a resource is added via `AddResource`. This seems to imply that you cannot have a `.resx` file that has no resources.

Is this intentional and I should be trying to have an "empty" resource file?

Or is there some other way to create an "empty" `.resx`?

Comment: Side note: how do you plan to use empty resource files?

Comment: It would just be a temporary file that has all the meta-data and usage, but simply doesn't have any `data` elements

Comment: I see - you are not actually planning to use it to load resources... I'd simply write static file in that case (I suspect empty resource files will have issues at run-time too and hence no one added handling for that case, but it is just my guess).

Comment: You can use AddMetaData (since it is also calling InitWriter) or if don't want to add even a metadata, use reflection to hack and call InitWriter yourself. I tried it and it worked and I got an empty resx file in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I derived my solution from @[Oguz Oguz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5497207/oguz-ozgul).

Whenever there are no resources I am adding a placeholder metadata element to force the ResourceWriter to create the necessary generator structure. The next time I generate the `.resx` if there are any resources I just don't add that metadata item.

```
var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(filename);
m_resources.ForEach(writer.AddResource);
if (! m_resource.Any()) writer.AddMetadata("", "");
writer.Close();
```